# Why doesn't git update my remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a checkout with two branches. One of them is the main branch in the "origin" remote, and is set up to track that (or so I believe). The other is the active branch, and only exists in this checkout.

Here's the output of `git branch -vv`:

```
  Official    9b44ada [origin/Official: behind 5] <commit message>
* MyBranch    aecc225 <commit message>
```

When I do a `git fetch`, the output is empty (I do believe I've got all the changes from there), but the `Official` branch remains like that: behind by 5 commits.

If I try a `git pull`, the fetch phase is similarly blank, and then I'm warned that there is no tracking information for `MyBranch` (which is expected).

Why isn't `git fetch` updating the remote tracking branch `Official`, and how do I get it to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `git fetch`, then it will update `origin/Official`, but it won't update your local branch `Official` to match it.

If you do a `git pull`, it will fetch, and also update your current branch (but not other branches) to match the remote branch, triggering a merge if needed.

To update the local `Official` branch to match the remote:

```
git checkout Official
git pull
```

Comment: Ooh, I see. I think in my case I'm probably best off just deleting the local `Official` branch and just merge from `origin/Official` whenever I need to, so that its permanently-behind status stops confusing me.